# PhpStorm highlight all instances of current selected variable (text)?

Tags: phpstorm

You can check this the image below, I've marked `$articles`, but I want everywhere in my file `$articles` to be marked, like in other editors, for example you can check image 2:

[image]

[image: image2]

I tried everything I found on Google but without success, most of them worked for PhpStorm 2017, but not for 2018.

Comment: *"I tried everything I found on Google but without success, most of them worked for PhpStorm 2017, but not for 2018."* So what did you found? The stuff like that should be highlighted by default ... which suggests that it's your custom Color Scheme that does not have colours setup for such variables. But there is also a plugin that can highlight currently select word in the whole file.

Comment: You are right, the problem comes from default theme.

Comment: What do you mean by *"the problem comes from default theme"*? From what I see you are NOT using one of the bundled color schemes... Anyway: `Settings/Preferences | Editor | Color Scheme | General | Code | Identifier under caret` should be the appropriate style. There is also BrowseWordAtCaret plugin that can highlight and quickly navigate between all matches in current file (highlighting might need to be enabled separately).

Comment: `Settings/Preferences | Editor | Color Scheme | General | Code | Identifier under caret` wasn't checked (background), so now to delete this question? Or you will post your comment as answer ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. `Settings/Preferences`
2. `Editor | Color Scheme | General | Code`
3. `Identifier under caret` and `Identifier under caret (write)`

These are the styles that allow to do what you want (Note: it works with **identifiers** only (e.g. variables/properties) and will not work with plain random words (e.g. a word from the string content). You may try **BrowseWordAtCaret plugin** if you need that to work with any word.

[image]

**P.S.** There is also `Search Results` section down below -- similar styles but for Find functionality.